# Filtering a nested ng-repeat: Hide parents that don't have children

Tags: angularjs

I want to make some kind of project list from a JSON file. The data structure (year, month, project) looks like this:

```
[{
    "name": "2013",
    "months": [{
        "name": "May 2013",
        "projects": [{
            "name": "2013-05-09 Project A"
        }, {
            "name": "2013-05-14 Project B"
        }, { ... }]
    }, { ... }]
}, { ... }]
```

I'm displaying all data using a nested `ng-repeat` and make it searchable by a filter bound to the query from an input box.

```
<input type="search" ng-model="query" placeholder="Suchen..." />

<div class="year" ng-repeat="year in data | orderBy:'name':true">
     <h1>{{year.name}}</h1>

    <div class="month" ng-repeat="month in year.months | orderBy:sortMonth:true">
         <h3>{{month.name}}</h3>

        <div class="project" ng-repeat="project in month.projects | filter:query | orderBy:'name'">
            <p>{{project.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I type "Project B" now, all the empty parent elements are still visible. How can I hide them? I tried some `ng-show` tricks, but the main problem seems so be, that I don't have access to any information about the parents filtered state.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/stekhn/y3ft0cwn/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best way to go is to implement a custom function in order to update a custom Array with the filtered data whenever the `query` changes. Like this:

```
$scope.query = '';
$scope.filteredData= angular.copy($scope.data);
$scope.updateFilteredData = function(newVal){
    var filtered = angular.copy($scope.data);
    filtered = filtered.map(function(year){ 
        year.children=year.children.map(function(month){
            month.children = $filter('filter')(month.children,newVal);
            return month;
        });
        return year;
    });
    $scope.filteredData = filtered.filter(function(year){
        year.children= year.children.filter(function(month){
            return month.children.length>0;
        });
        return year.children.length>0;
    });
}
```

And then your view will look like this:

```
    <input type="search" ng-model="query" ng-change="updateFilteredData(query)"
           placeholder="Search..." />
    <div class="year" ng-repeat="year in filteredData | orderBy:'name':true">
         <h1>{{year.name}}</h1>
        <div class="month" ng-repeat="month in year.children | orderBy:sortMonth:true">
            <h3>{{month.name}}</h3>
            <div class="project" ng-repeat="project in month.children | orderBy:'name'">
                <p>{{project.name}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7056coff/1/)

---

### Why not a custom `$filter` for this?

**Efficiency**: the nature of the `$diggest` cycle would make it much less efficient. The only problem is that this solution won't be as easy to re-use as a custom `$filter` would. However, that custom `$filter` wouldn't be very reusable either, since its logic would be very dependent on this concrete data structure.

---

### IE8 Support

If you need this to work on IE8 you will have to either use jQuery to replace the `filter` and `map` functions or to ensure that those functions are defined, like this:
(BTW: if you need IE8 support there is absolutely nothing wrong with using jQuery for these kind of things.)

**filter**:

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun/*, thisArg*/) {
    'use strict';

    if (this === void 0 || this === null) {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var res = [];
    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t) {
        var val = t[i];
        if (fun.call(thisArg, val, i, t)) {
          res.push(val);
        }
      }
    }
    return res;
  };
}
```

**map**

```
if (!Array.prototype.map) {
  Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {
    var T, A, k;
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(" this is null or not defined");
    }
    var O = Object(this);
    var len = O.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + " is not a function");
    }
    if (thisArg) {
      T = thisArg;
    }
    A = new Array(len);
    k = 0;
    while(k < len) {
      var kValue, mappedValue;
      if (k in O) {
        kValue = O[ k ];
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
        A[ k ] = mappedValue;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return A;
  };      
}
```

---

### Acknowledgement

I want to thank [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) for [his feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684887/filtering-a-nested-ng-repeat-hide-parents-that-dont-have-children/26685021?noredirect=1#comment41971616_26685021).

Comment: Thanks for this efficient and easy to implement answer. That's the first good answer to the filtering nested ng-repeats problem I've seen here on Stackoverflow. I like the use of map and filter as this is very modern, straightforward Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You basically have to filter the months to only keep the ones having at least one filtered project, and you also have to filter the years to only keep those having at least one filtered month.

This can be easily achieved using the following code:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.query = '';
    $scope.monthHasVisibleProject = function(month) {
        return $filter('filter')(month.children, $scope.query).length > 0;
    };

    $scope.yearHasVisibleMonth = function(year) {
        return $filter('filter')(year.children, $scope.monthHasVisibleProject).length > 0;
    };
```

and in the view:

```
<div class="year" ng-repeat="year in data | filter:yearHasVisibleMonth | orderBy:'name':true">
             <h1>{{year.name}}</h1>

            <div class="month" ng-repeat="month in year.children | filter:monthHasVisibleProject | orderBy:sortMonth:true">
```

This is quite inefficient though, since to know if a year is accepted, you filter all its months, and for each month, you filter all its projects. So, unless the performance is good enough for your amount of data, you should probably apply the same principle but by persisting the accepted/rejected state of each object (project, then month, then year) every time the query is modified.

Comment: +1 but could you please have a look at my answer and let me know what your thoughts are? I think that the solution that I'm suggesting is more efficient. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution basically implements what I suggest in the second part of my answer. I would use ng-change rather than use a watch.

Comment: Thank you, this is an easy solution to my problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested: Yesterday I found another approach for solving this problem, which strikes me as rather inefficient. The functions gets called for every child again  while typing the query. Not nearly as nice as [Josep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544439/josep)'s solution.

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.query = '';

    $scope.searchString = function () {

        return function (item) {
            var string = JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase();
            var words = $scope.query.toLowerCase();

            if (words) {
                var filterBy = words.split(/\s+/);

                if (!filterBy.length) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }

            return filterBy.every(function (word) {
                var exists = string.indexOf(word);

                if(exists !== -1){
                    return true;
                }
            });
        };
    };
};
```

And in the view:

```
<div class="year" ng-repeat="year in data | filter:searchString() | orderBy:'name':true">
     <h1>{{year.name}}</h1>

    <div class="month" ng-repeat="month in year.children | filter:searchString() | orderBy:sortMonth:true">
         <h3>{{month.name}}</h3>

        <div class="project" ng-repeat="project in month.children | filter:searchString() | orderBy:'name'">
            <p>{{project.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stekhn/stv55sxg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work? Using a filtered variable and checking the length of it..

```
<input type="search" ng-model="query" placeholder="Suchen..." />

    <div class="year" ng-repeat="year in data | orderBy:'name':true" ng-show="filtered.length != 0">
     <h1>{{year.name}}</h1>

    <div class="month" ng-repeat="month in year.months | orderBy:sortMonth:true">
         <h3>{{month.name}}</h3>

        <div class="project" ng-repeat="project in filtered = (month.projects | filter:query) | orderBy:'name'">
            <p>{{project.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```